# React: Props are not being passed to children

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have this parent which clone and injects props `Login` to the children:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavMenu } from '../navigations/NavMenu';
import { Login } from './account/Login';

export class Layout extends Component {
    static displayName = Layout.name;

    render() {
        const loginForm = new Login();
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                return React.cloneElement(child, { loginForm: loginForm });
            }
            return child;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {loginForm.render()}
                <NavMenu />
                <Container>
                    {childrenWithProps}
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is one of the children:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { http } from '../../helpers/Http';

export class FetchData extends Component {
    static displayName = FetchData.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { forecasts: [], loading: true };
        let x = this.props.loginForm; <-- THIS IS UNDEFINED
    }

    .......
}
```

The `this.props.loginForm` is undefined. How can I inject props correctly?

---

### EDIT

This is the `Login` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { show: false };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.showLogin = this.showLogin.bind(this);
    }

    showLogin() {
        this.setState({
            show: true
        });
    }

    login() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className={this.state.show ? "login-form " : "login-form hide"} onSubmit={this.login()}>
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input required type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input required type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to call `showLogin()` from `FetchData`. If the user is not authorized when fetching the data, I want to show the login modal.

[image: Assigned in Layout component]

[image: Does not get passed successfully at FetchData component]

Comment: Honestly, this smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. I think that what you're trying to achieve would be better implemented with [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am confused because my case is kind of different. I need to passed down an instantiated component from parent to children.

Comment: What's the use case here? What will the children do with `Login`? Could you include the code for `./account/Login` and more about what `FetchData` does with the `Login` instance?

Comment: I want to call `showLogin()` from `FetchData` component

Comment: Looks like a clear case of needing to [lift up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) which determines whether the login form should be shown. You'll want to move the `show` state up to `Layout` (or somewhere higher, if appropriate) and pass that down as a prop to `Login`, and the function for changing that state just directly to the children.

Comment: I have tried to move the state into `Layout`, but the problem is that my children does not have the prop assigned to it. I assigned the children prop to be a function to show login `React.cloneElement(child, { showLogin: this.showLogin });`. When I check inside the constructor of the child, `this.props.showLogin` is undefined. So the real problem is the props passing is incorrect